# Where to register attribute routing custom class constraints

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-core

I am trying to create first API app witn vNext, being familiar with WebAPI. I'd like to use attribute routes with type constraints. Where do I write some sort of configuration to map constraint name to custom classes/enums? I tried `Configure` method in `Startup.cs` but have no idea what to do with `IApplicationBuilder`. Searching at https://github.com/aspnet/Routing gave nothing.

I suppose, there should be a place to plug in this piece of code somewhere (for enums constraint):

```
routes.MapAttributeRoutes(cfg =>
{
    // ...
    cfg.InlineRouteConstraints.Add("customenum", typeof(EnumRouteConstraint<MyEnum>));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inline constraints are configured in `options`. The pattern for defining options is a common pattern in ASPNET 5, the code below is in `Startup.cs`

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    /// rest of the code

    serviceCollection.Configure<RouteOptions>(routeOptions =>
    {
        routeOptions =>
            routeOptions.ConstraintMap
            .Add("yourstring", typeof(YourConstraintType)));
    }
}
```

Since the options definition in startup area of the code changes across versions, I pasted something that works in latest bits. You might have to adjust based on what version you have in your project.

[Here is](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/27432d94530405f424e9015c8c5311907bd48b3f/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L26-L29) how MVC adds the custom `exists` constraint. Note this gets called from `AddMvc()`.

[Here is](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/samples/MvcSample.Web/Startup.cs) the MVC startup.cs sample.

[Here is](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1687) the issue tracking adding the sample and test for this scenario.

Also note that we now support inline constraints also in conventional routes.

Comment: Thank you for the sample and for links. I see you're a part of ASPNET5 team, could you please point me to actual samples/docs collection, if any? I tried to find something to start with, everything seems scattered through different repos on GitHub and articles on asp.net website.

Comment: At the moment stuff is indeed scattered. But for MVC itself a good location will be the MVC repo itself where we have two types of samples:
1. The samples folder (I point to that in the original post)
2. The Tests/FunctionalTests/WebSites folder - In this folder we have (mostly) full sites showing off use cases of individual features. They are not primarily intended to be samples, but they are pretty extensive.

Extensive documentation is something we are still working on, there is definitely more we can do about it.